# Safari doesn't play .mp4 videos

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, safari, mp4

This works fine on Chrome, but not on Safari.

```
<video id="video" class="video" preload="metadata" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" >
   <source src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 3):

The mp4 video's Codecs is H.264.
To play this video, I had to convert this mp4 to HEVC.  Voila, this solved it!

```
<video id="video" class="video" preload="metadata" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" >
            <!-- for safari - HEVC -->
            <source src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
            <!-- for chrome - H264 -->
            <source src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: You could include a default, video not supported as a fall-back in your adventures to set your project up and test. You'd do that by adding below all the sources <p>ERROR RUN!?</p>

Comment: I don't understand... they point to the same file. ?? I'm not spotting the difference.

Answer (score 1):

I added a couple of more lines of code because this background video wasn't playing on mobile(iphone chrome and safari)

```
<video id="video" class="video" preload="metadata" autoplay muted loop playsinline>
        <!-- below is for safari - HEVC format -->
        <source src="images/home-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <!-- for google -  H264 format -->
        <source src="images/hero-video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <!-- for mobile -->
        <source src="images/hero-video.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="images/hero-video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Now I'm having an issue with this video not playing on Android(Chrome).. smh

Answer (score 1):

A nice and simple hack is to simply duplicate the file and make use of the `.m4v` extension at the end instead of `.mp4` and use content type `video/x-m4v` instead of `video/mp4`.

example:

```
<video preload="metadata" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" >
  <!-- for safari or iOS or anything Apple -->
  <source src="images/video.m4v" type="video/x-m4v">
  <!-- for chrome, firefox, android and remainig friends -->
  <source src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M4V

Answer (score 0):

You need to add "playsinline" attribute for autoplay in safari.

```
<video playsinline id="video" class="video" preload="metadata" autoplay="" loop="" muted="" >
   <source src="images/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide